# Why is streamlit messing up my Plotly chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, streamlit

Importing the streamlit library into my Python code has changed my Plotly chart into black and white. The same description can also be found on the Plotly [github](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/6897) page.

My problem can be replicated with the following steps:

**First of all, I have the following system configuration:**

```
Streamlit version: 1.23.1
Plotly version: 5.15
Python version: 3.11
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro (64-bit)
Browser: Microsoft Edge Version 114.0.1823.58 (64-bit)
Virtual environment: miniconda 23.3.1
```

**Step 1. Setup a new environment at the command prompt**

```
conda create -n test python==3.11
conda activate test
pip install numpy pandas plotly==5.15 streamlit==1.23.1
```

**Step 2. Launch Python at the command prompt**

```
python
```

**Step 3. Create a Plotly chart without importing the streamlit library by running these code **

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))
fig.show()
```

**Step 4: My Plotly plot looks like this (expected behavior)**
[image]

**Step 5: Import the streamlit library and re-run the same code.**

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))
fig.show()
```

**Step 6: My plotly chart becomes black and white like this (unexpected behavior)**
[image]

**Step 7: It also affected Pandas's plot with plotly backend**

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend='plotly'

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10)))
fig = df.plot()
fig.show()
```

[image]

**Does anyone know how to fix this issue?**

Comment: I have confirmed the same condition as yours. I don't know why, but if I update the template with default values, it reverts back.

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_layout(template='plotly')`

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works on the `go.Figure()`. However, when I try it on pandas `df.plot()` with plotly backend `import pandas as pd; pd.options.plotting.backend='plotly'; df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10)); df.plot()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [temporary solution](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/4261#issuecomment-1605621516) works. Hopefully streamlit could find the permanent solution in the future.

```
import streamlit as st
...
...
# reset Plotly theme after streamlit import
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates.default = 'plotly'
```